# Fix multiple image size with same dimension in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

my code is inside a ListView Widget. i am having a problem with my images, since each one of them have a dimensions which is different than the other ones. i want them to appear all with the same dimension, but some of them is being bigger than the others.

note : i have used Width and Height and it didn't help

[image]

i want both of them to be with the same dimension but the second one is bigger !
i have even tried the BoxFit method as well and didn't help.
here is my code sample:

```
ListView(
  children: List.generate(
    sandwichFood.length,
    (index) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        decoration: _foodDecor(),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  sandwichFood[index],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Price : ${sandwichPrice[index]}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(sandwichImage[index]),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: wrap Image with SizedBox and give it height and width

Comment: bro sadly it didnt help and it still the same , do you have any other suggerstions ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Image` class has parameter `fit`. Try to use it:

```
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(sandwichImage[index]),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            )
```

Comment: hi bro i told you i have used BoxFit methode before but didnt help , the borders of the images is beigh deleted with it and only the center apears now .

Comment: Sorry missed it. You have 2 choices to either fit images or resize them.

Comment: @MiranGAMER `BoxFit.cover` is the best solution - what would you expect if the aspect ratio of the images is not 1 : 1? what if the image width is 4 times bigger than height? would you like to squeeze it to fit 200x200 area? if so, use `BoxFit.fill` and you will see how ugly it looks

Comment: yes i know fill methode will stretch it and it will looks ugly , thank you for your time , appreciate your help .